# Distribute NonCommutativeMultiply over Times

Tags: algebraic-manipulation, ncalgebra

Is there a method to transform

```
(a1 * a2) ** (b1 * b2)
```

into

```
(a1 ** b1) * (a2 ** b2)
```

I am trying to transform non-commutative products based on the number at the end of the variable in order to replace it with a `NCReplace` (from the `NCAlgebra` package) later.

Answer (score 3):

```
Thread[(a1*a2) ** (b1*b2), Times]
```

> a1 ** b1 a2 ** b2