# Threading Functions Specifying the Head and Level

Tags: algebraic-manipulation

I'm trying to thread a function only on the second level of an expression. For example

> Thread[(a * b) ** (c * d),Times]

gives

> (a ** c) * (b ** d)

However

> Thread[2(a * b) ** (c * d),Times]

gives

> 2(a * b) ** (c * d)

instead of

> 2(a ** c) * (b ** d)

How do I specify that I only wish to Thread on the second level of Times?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise. 2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour)! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by [clicking the checkmark sign](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/)!

Comment: Related/duplicate: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/175708/distribute-noncommutativemultiply-over-times

Comment: I suspect you're the same user as Daniel in the Q&A I just linked.  If so, you should [merge your accounts](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts) so that you will be the owner of your own posts and be able to edit them, accept answers to your questions, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the documentation:

> Thread[f[args],h]
>
> threads f over any objects with head h that appear in args.

`f` is the outermost.
Compare the `FullForm` of both expressions. In the second case the outermost is `Times`, not `NonCommutativeMultiply`

```
FullForm[(a*b) ** (c*d)]
(*output*)  NonCommutativeMultiply[Times[a, b], Times[c, d]]

FullForm[2 (a*b) ** (c*d)]
(*output*)  Times[2, NonCommutativeMultiply[Times[a, b], Times[c, d]]]
```

Simple replacement rule can do what you want

```
2 (a*b) ** (c*d) /. 
 NonCommutativeMultiply[a__] :> Thread[NonCommutativeMultiply[a], Times]

(*output*) 2 a ** c b ** d
```